# Retrieve state values from many of the same child component react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a screen that contains many of the same `CustomSlider` component. I would like to retrieve the slider values from every slider.

What is best practice for doing this in react native?

Here's a minimum working example, with 3 sliders:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import MultiSlider from "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider";

class CustomSlider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      multiSliderValue: [1, 9]
    }
  }
  multiSliderValuesChange = values => {
    this.setState({multiSliderValue: values});
  };
  render(){
    return (
      <MultiSlider
        values={this.state.multiSliderValue}
        onValuesChange={this.multiSliderValuesChange}
        min={0}
        max={10}
        step={1}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }
  get_slider_values = () => {
    // what is best practice to access the values of every slider here?
    // eg an object like this
    const slider_values = [[1.4, 7.4], [4.3, 7.0], [1.9, 3.2]]
    return slider_values
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 50}}>
        <CustomSlider />
        <CustomSlider />
        <CustomSlider />
        <Text>{`The slider values are: ` + JSON.stringify(this.get_slider_values())}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a complex solution. The way that I would handle this is to manage the state in the parent component. The `CustomSlider` doesn't really need to know its state. As the parent component needs to know the state of the sliders it is better to handle it there.

So as the parent component is going to handle the state this means we need to make some changes to what you are doing.

1. Set initial values in the parent component for the state of each of the sliders. This is important, it makes it means that even if the user doesn't touch the sliders we know the values of them.
2. Pass a function to each of the sliders that calls back to the parent component.
3. As the parent component is controlling the state we can remove the state from the `CustomSlider`. This gives a few options we could leave it as a `Component`, change it to a `PureComponent` or go one step further an change it to a `Functional Component` If the slider doesn't really need to know its state then the last option should be best for performance.

---

Here is how I would refactor your `App.js`

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sliderValues: [[1, 9],[1, 9],[1, 9]] // we should control the state here
    };
  }

  // this uses function currying to bind the function and pass a value to it
  onChange = (index) => (values) => {
    this.setState( prevState => {
      let sliderValues = prevState.sliderValues;
      sliderValues[index] = values;
      return {
        sliderValues
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 50}}>
        <CustomSlider intialValues={this.state.sliderValues[0]} onChange={this.onChange(0)}/>
        <CustomSlider intialValues={this.state.sliderValues[1]} onChange={this.onChange(1)}/>
        <CustomSlider intialValues={this.state.sliderValues[2]} onChange={this.onChange(2)}/>
        <Text>{`The slider values are: ` + JSON.stringify(this.state.sliderValues)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice how we don't actually need a function to get the values of the sliders as they are stored in state. That means we can access the sliders' values directly by using `this.state.sliderValues`.

---

Here is your `CustomComponent` refactored to work with the above code:

```
class CustomSlider extends Component {  // this could easily be swapped for a PureComponent 
  render(){
    return (
      <MultiSlider
        values={this.props.intialValues}
        onValuesChange={this.props.onChange}
        min={0}
        max={10}
        step={1}
      />
    )
  }
```

Notice how it doesn't need to manage state at all as the parent component is handling it. It also means that we can remove a lot of code that isn't actually necessary. This is why I think we can go one step further and make it a `Functional Component`

```
const CustomSlider = ({intialValues, onChange}) => {
  return (
     <MultiSlider
        values={intialValues}
        onValuesChange={onChange}
        min={0}
        max={10}
        step={1}
      />
  )
}
```

If however if the `CustomSlider` needs to know its state because it is doing something more than capturing the values of the slider then you can easily add state to it by using it as a `Component` or a `PureComponent`.

---

## Snack

Here is a snack showing the above code working. I have shown all three possible components and have used them in the `App.js`. There isn't much difference in how they look, but your use case will determine which one that you use. https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/multisliders

---

## Best Practice

The best practice is to go for the simplest solution that you can find. Ideally that would be a `Functional Component`, then a `PureComponent`, and finally a `Component`. It is also important to think about where and how the state is going to be used. Some questions that I ask myself are:

- Does a component really need to know its own state?
- Where do I plan on using that state?
- How long do I need these state values for?
- Do I need to persist that state?
- What tools are available to me based on what I am currently using?
- Do I really need to add another dependency or more to make this work?

If you need the values from the sliders in multiple places in your app you can use some of the features that are provided by `react-native` or your navigation to pass these values around. Redux and MobX are big overheads in terms of complexity and should only really be used if you need a global state management system, for the majority of cases they can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the state dynamically by some key given to each child, and access each ones state by the key you give it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass a closure from parent component to `CustomSlider`s as props and monitor the changes.

```
<CustomSlider idx={n} 
              theClosurePassedThrough= (n, values) => {
// update the parents states here accordingly
              }
>
```

Then call this closure at appropriate time.

```
multiSliderValuesChange = values => {
  this.setState({multiSliderValue: values});
  this.props.theClosurePassedThrough(this.props.idx, values);
};
```

The best practice, though, is to use MobX or Redux.